# why don't trust valid intermediate x509 certificates?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, x509

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
 |   |
 D   E
```

when E (or C) is verifying D's certificate he needs to trust B also.
is there a way to avoid having to explicitly add B's cert to E's CA store?

using openssl, is there the way to automate the retrieval of B's cert either from the client or another source (maybe a field like issuerDistributionPoint in D's certificate)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: ***`E`*** (or ***`C`*** ) cannot be used in a path to verify ***`D`***  certificate. Also see [RFC 4158, Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure: Certification Path Building](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4158).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to avoid having to explicitly add B's cert to E's CA store?

The common way is to send all intermediate certificates along with the leaf certificate inside the TLS handshake. For instance if you connect to google.com you get the following certificate chain provided by the server within the TLS handshake:

```
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
```

Using the intermediate certificates (1,2) the client then can build the trust chain from the leaf certificate (0) up to the locally stored trusted CA (`/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority` in this case).

Of course you might also add the intermediate certificates as trusted in the clients. But since there are a lot more which also change more often than the trusted root certificates you would need a bit more memory but you would also update your clients regularly with the new intermediate certificates.

> using openssl, is there the way to automate the retrieval of B's cert either from the client or another source (maybe a field like issuerDistributionPoint in D's certificate)?

openssl does not provide specific tools to deal with this. The desktop browser Google Chrome will actually try to download missing intermediate certificates from the internet, probably based on the information in the Authority Information Access part of the certificate. But I'm not aware of other browsers (apart from other Chromium derivates like Opera) doing this.

Comment: Also see the [PKI "which directory" problem](http://www.google.com/search?num=40&q=pki+"which+directory"+problem).

Comment: @jww: +1. Not every certificate contains the information in the Authority Information Access and then you don't really know where you should get the missing intermediate from.